# How to put other backpack to main backpack?

Tags: java

I tried to put some items to the backpack.
I can add and remove some items, but I can't put another backpack in main backpack.

*After running the program I can see backpack and some items inside:*

Backpack (0.1 kg, 0.5 l) with
1: Ball (1.0 kg, 3.0 l)
2: Torch (0.5 kg, 1.0 l)
3: Box1 (5.0 kg, 25.0 l)
Total: 6.6, 29.5

*Backpack with removed second item*

Backpack (0.1 kg, 0.5 l) with
1: Ball (1.0 kg, 3.0 l)
2: Box1 (5.0 kg, 25.0 l)
Total: 6.1, 28.5

*Backpack with other backpack*

Backpack (0.1 kg, 0.5 l) with
1: Ball (1.0 kg, 3.0 l)
2: Box1 (5.0 kg, 25.0 l)
3: Backpack (0.01 kg, 0.1 l)
Total: 6.109999999999999, 28.6

but I can't see other backpack with its items...

*I ought to see:*

Backpack (0.1 kg, 0.5 l) with
1: Ball (1 kg, 3 l)
2: Torch (0.5 kg, 1 l)
3: Box1 (5 kg, 25 l)
Total: 5.6 kg 29.5 l
Backpack (0.1 kg, 0.5 l) with
1: Ball (1 kg, 3 l)
2: Box1 (5 kg, 25 l)
Total: 5.1 kg 28.5 l

Backpack (0.1 kg, 0.5 l) with
1: Ball (1 kg, 3 l)
2: Box1 (5 kg, 25 l)
3: Backpack (0.01 kg, 0.1 l) with
1: Box2 (3 g, 8 l)
Total: 3.01 kg, 8.1 l
Total: 5.1 kg 28.5 l

Maybe someone has any suggestions?

My code is here:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
 
class TableSafe {
    ArrayList<Thing> item = new ArrayList<>();
}
 
class Thing {
    protected double weight;
    protected double volume;
    protected String name;
 
    public Thing(String name, double weight, double volume) {
        if (name != null)
            this.name = name;
        else
            this.name = "";
        this.weight = Math.max(weight, 0.0);
        this.volume = Math.max(volume, 0.0);
    }
    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public double getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " (" + weight + " kg, " + volume + " l)";
    }
}
class Backpack {
    double weight;
    double volume;
    double maxWeight;
    double maxVolume;
    String name;
    TableSafe element = new TableSafe();
 
    public Backpack(double weight, double volume, double maxWeight, double maxVolume) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.maxWeight = maxWeight;
        this.maxVolume = maxVolume;
 
    }
    void add(Thing thing) {
        element.item.add(thing);
 
    }
    void add(Backpack small) {
        add(new Thing(Backpack.class.getSimpleName(), small.weight, small.volume));
    }
    public void remove(int index) {
        element.item.remove(index - 1);
    }
    public void printContent() {
        System.out.println(new Thing(Backpack.class.getSimpleName(), this.weight, this.volume) + " with");
        double totalWeight = 0.0;
        double totalVolume = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < element.item.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print((i + 1) + ": ");
            Thing thing = element.item.get(i);
            System.out.println(thing);
            totalWeight += thing.weight;
            totalVolume += thing.volume;
 
        }
 
        System.out.println("Total: " + (totalWeight + this.weight) + ", " + (totalVolume + this.volume));
        System.out.println();
    }
    public double getWeight() {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < element.item.size(); i++) {
            total += element.item.get(i).getWeight();
        }
        return total + this.weight;
    }
    public double getVolume() {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < element.item.size(); i++) {
            total += element.item.get(i).getVolume();
        }
        return total + this.volume;
    }
    public String getName() {
        for (int i = 0; i < element.item.size(); i++) {
            String name = Backpack.class.getSimpleName();
        }
        return name;
    }
}
 
class Box extends Thing {
    protected double height;
    protected double width;
    protected double depth;
    protected double volume;
 
    public Box(String name, double weight,
               double height, double width, double depth) {
        super(name, weight, height * width * depth * 1000);
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.depth = depth;
        volume = height * width * depth * 1000;
    }
    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
 
    public double getWidht() {
        return width;
    }
 
    public double getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }
}
public class Safe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Backpack b = new Backpack(0.100, 0.5, 40, 50);
        b.add(new Thing("Ball", 1, 3));
        b.add(new Thing("Torch", 0.5, 1));
        b.add(new Box("Box1", 5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5));
        b.printContent();
        b.remove(2);
        b.printContent();
        System.out.println(b.getWeight());
        System.out.println(b.getVolume());
        System.out.println();
 
        Backpack small = new Backpack(0.01, 0.1, 5, 13);
       // b = small;
        small.add(new Box("Box2", 3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2));
        small.add(new Box("Box3", 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2));
        b.add(small);
 
        b.printContent();
 
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be easier if you overrode `toString()` in `BackPack`.  In `BackPack.printContents()`, you need to check if the item is a back pack and call its `printContents()` to print everything inside it.

Comment: Not related to your question, which @markspace answered in his comment, but nonetheless... Why does class `Box` have a `volume` member when the superclass, `Thing`, also has a `volume` member? Why does class `Backpack` have a `name` member which is never assigned a value? Note that method `getName()`, in class `Backpack`, returns the class member which is always null since it is never assigned a value. In method `remove()`, in class `Backpack`, you should check the value of the method parameter. What happens if the value is zero?

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially rehashing what [markspace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338547/markspace) commented but you should probably use a bit more encapsulation. So you should probably make it so whenever you want to print the contents of a backpack you just call `System.out.println(backpack.toString())` and then inside your backpack's `toString()` method you don't actually print anything at all and let that be handled by calling the class.

Instead, use something like a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to append everything together as you were doing. Then, for each item in the backpack, just call its toString() method. That way, if it's a backpack, will continue just continue the same logic and print its contents. Once it's done, just return the stringBuilder.toString() and it'll print outside.

This helps abstract the logic and makes it easier if you ever want to change how the backpack behaves, which is best practice for object-orienting programming.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use for loop to add items to Main Backpack.
2. You are using Java. Java is a OOP support language, You should use OOP Encapsulation to protect data of Backpack.

I hope this code may help you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class TableSafe {

    ArrayList<Thing> item = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Thing {

    protected double weight;
    protected double volume;
    protected String name;

    public Thing(String name, double weight, double volume) {
        if (name != null) {
            this.name = name;
        } else {
            this.name = "";
        }
        this.weight = Math.max(weight, 0.0);
        this.volume = Math.max(volume, 0.0);
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " (" + weight + " kg, " + volume + " l)";
    }
}

class Backpack {

    double weight;
    double volume;
    double maxWeight;
    double maxVolume;
    String name;
    TableSafe element = new TableSafe();

    public Backpack(double weight, double volume, double maxWeight, double maxVolume) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.maxWeight = maxWeight;
        this.maxVolume = maxVolume;

    }

    void add(Thing thing) {
        element.item.add(thing);

    }

    void add(Backpack small) {
        add(new Thing(Backpack.class.getSimpleName(), small.weight, small.volume));
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
        element.item.remove(index - 1);
    }

    public void printContent() {
        System.out.println(new Thing(Backpack.class.getSimpleName(), this.weight, this.volume) + " with");
        double totalWeight = 0.0;
        double totalVolume = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < element.item.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print((i + 1) + ": ");
            Thing thing = element.item.get(i);
            System.out.println(thing);
            totalWeight += thing.weight;
            totalVolume += thing.volume;

        }

        System.out.println("Total: " + (totalWeight + this.weight) + ", " + (totalVolume + this.volume));
        System.out.println();
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < element.item.size(); i++) {
            total += element.item.get(i).getWeight();
        }
        return total + this.weight;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < element.item.size(); i++) {
            total += element.item.get(i).getVolume();
        }
        return total + this.volume;
    }

    public String getName() {
        for (int i = 0; i < element.item.size(); i++) {
            String name = Backpack.class.getSimpleName();
        }
        return name;
    }
}

class Box extends Thing {

    protected double height;
    protected double width;
    protected double depth;
    protected double volume;

    public Box(String name, double weight,
            double height, double width, double depth) {
        super(name, weight, height * width * depth * 1000);
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.depth = depth;
        volume = height * width * depth * 1000;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public double getWidht() {
        return width;
    }

    public double getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }
}

public class Safe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Backpack b = new Backpack(0.100, 0.5, 40, 50);
        b.add(new Thing("Ball", 1, 3));
        b.add(new Thing("Torch", 0.5, 1));
        b.add(new Box("Box1", 5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5));
        b.printContent();
        b.remove(2);
        b.printContent();
        System.out.println(b.getWeight());
        System.out.println(b.getVolume());
        System.out.println();

        Backpack small = new Backpack(0.01, 0.1, 5, 13);
        // b = small;
        small.add(new Box("Box2", 3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2));
        small.add(new Box("Box3", 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2));
        for (int i = 0; i < small.element.item.size(); i++) {
            b.add(small.element.item.get(i));
        }
        //b.add(small);

        b.printContent();

    }
}
```